# Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

trato de hacer un código en android que me invoque un reloj  y que me altere la lista que esta directamente abajo

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AgendarHora extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnAgregarH;
    TextView txtHoraP;
    int hora, minutos;
    private ArrayList<String> horas;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String rth = getIntent().getStringExtra("ruta");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendar_hora);
        btnAgregarH = findViewById(R.id.btnAgregarH);
        txtHoraP = findViewById(R.id.txtHoraP);
        btnAgregarH.setOnClickListener(this);
        list = findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, horas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(v==btnAgregarH){
            hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minutos = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    txtHoraP.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                }
            },hora,minutos,false);
            tpd.show();
        }
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        btnAgregarH.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                horas.add(txtHoraP.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Pero al entrar a esta Acitvity, me lanza el siguiente error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int
>
> java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

En la línea de

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: si tienes un NPE es porque estas usando una variable el cual no posee datos dentro, creo que es porque estas teniendo un inconveniente con tu adaptador ya que le estas enviando un arreglo vacio llamado "horas", recuerda que el onClickListener es un oyente de eventos, y va a ejecuarse cada vez que tu presiones click sobre una view (si esta tiene el atributo clickeable), para resolver tu problema creo que tienes que llenar el "ArrayList<String> horas" y luego se lo envias al adapter.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno el error indica que llamas el método `size()` en una instancia con valor null, esto seguramente se produce internamente en el método `getItemCount()` del `ArrayAdapter`.

Si revisas el código, estas declarando la variable `horas` la cual debe contener un ArrayList de elementos tipo String, pero esta nunca es inicializada ni llenada, por lo tanto tiene un valor null

```
public class AgendarHora extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {       
    ...
    ...
    private ArrayList<String> horas;
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ...
        ... 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, horas);
    }
  ...
  ...
}
```

---

Para solucionar este problema, como ejemplo, inicializa y llena tu `ArrayList` de esta forma:

```
public class AgendarHora extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {       
    ...
    ...
    private ArrayList<String> horas = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ...
        ... 
        horas.add("elemento 1");
        horas.add("elemento 2");
        horas.add("elemento 3");
        horas.add("elemento 4");
        horas.add("elemento 5");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, horas);
    }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que el problema reside en que no has inicializado el ArrayList horas que le pasas como parametro al constructor de adapter.

```
private ArrayList<String> horas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.